# Does my 2005 Toyota Avalon not have an internal fusebox panel?

Tags: repair, fuse-panel

### Here is by background

There is a broken rear retractable sunscreen in my Toyota Avalon that makes a *SUPER ANNOYING NOISE* when the vehicle is put into reverse.

I just want to disable the thing, and apparently there is a way to do it, as shown in a video that depicts the vehicle owner removing the relevant fuse from the interior fusebox panel.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nnQ6WTp7Qo

### Here is my problem

I tried to do this on my own vehicle, but there is a "Knee-Emergency-Airbag" where I expected the interior fusebox panel to be.

Does this mean my vehicle does not have an interior fusebox panel at all?

Is there another place it might be located?

I don't want to have to remove the whole rear seat, just to get this thing out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fuse panel on the left side of steering column, you would need to remove the lower knee panel to see it, consult the owners manual to find the fuse for the rear sunshade.

There is also a fuse panel under the hood in the Engine compartment on the drivers side fender well.

[image]